# What happened to Jim Paprocki's brother?

Tags: character, banged-up-abroad

I recently watched [Locked Up Abroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banged_Up_Abroad)'s episode [Plane Crash Marijuana](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5794146/?ref_=ttep_ep1).

A key character is Jim Paprocki's brother (whose name I can't recall).
In the episode it isn't explained what ever happened to him when Jim left. So...

What happened to Jim Paprocki's brother?

Comment: This is my first question here. I'm not at all familiar with the tags so if anyone can properly tag this question, I appreciate it. Input how to improve the question is also welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: If you google Kurt Paprocki nothing turns up. I´m not sure there ever was a brother

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing,I didn't see anything about Kurt going home in the show!!

Answer (score 0):

They said in the program that Kurt could escape when he was taken to an audience, and he arrived safely to USA.

Comment: Can you tell me when in the show do they say that (if not exactly, an estimate will be enough)? I totally missed it. Thanks.